# Match numbers of commas in a string with value of left and right that aren't both numeric

Tags: regex

Suppose I have the following string:

`abc,400,00,foo,bar,34,000,,hello,bye`

What would the proper regex be to match the number of commas that have a character both on the left and right side though both characters can't be numeric, and non can be other commas.

In the example string, the commas I placed inside the parentheses would be counted, the rest not.

`abc(,)400,00(,)foo(,)bar(,)34,000,,hello(,)by`

Comment: So there has to be a character on the left AND right though BOTH can't be numeric. 1 being numeric is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match `,` between word characters by use of [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html). Now to exclude those that are NOT preceded AND followed by a digit, this condition can be checked with [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
\b,\b(?<!\d.(?=\d))
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/L4hOwX/1) - Or *without* word boundaries e.g. [`(?<!,),(?!,)(?<!\d.(?=\d))`](https://regex101.com/r/L4hOwX/2)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can user OR in your regex with two possible cases

Comment: Why are you using `[A-z]`? this will match the same as `[A-Za-z_\`^\\[\]]`, https://regex101.com/r/UfYi2E/1

Comment: Yeah you are right, I had no idea that it will work like this. Probably should be replaced by [A-Za-z]

Answer (score 0):

This should also work  -

`(?<=[^\d,]),`

Comment: This is not quite there since a case it won't detect is numeric,alpha (00,foo)

Comment: oh you are right - I thot one look behind will do the job unfortunately I missed it, therefore, need to add more conditions - [^\d,],(?=\d|[a-zA-Z])|\d,[^\d,]